# Aws rekognition video streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm a newbie.
Is aws rekognition video stream (streaming using kinesis vs) able to recognize objects like its images-based counterpart? This is probably obvious but I was not able to find any evidence online of this. Any helpful resource is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> You can use Amazon Rekognition Video to detect and recognize faces in
> streaming video.

AWS Rekognition [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/streaming-video.html)

You will need a Rekognition stream [processor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/using-rekognition-video-stream-processor.html)

Comment: Can I use rekognition video streams, for example, to recognize objects?

Comment: @Deblazz yes you can [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/labels-detecting-labels-video.html). Objects are called labels. "A label or a tag is an object, scene, or concept found in an image or video based on its contents." [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/labels.html). I would highly suggest first reading the Rekognition documentation, they have done a good job outlining the 99% use cases for this service and can answer most, if not all, of your questions.